# How to Restore differential backup in case of server failure

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups, database-restore

Backup and Restore plan

```
Full -08:00 PM

Diff - 02:00 PM

Diff - 05:00 PM
```

Recovery model : simple

i am taking backup(.bak) in (Network PC) different location

When i am trying to restore Full Database With No Recovery It gets restored Properly but i am unable to take backup of differential backup file it says 'Unable to Create restore plan due to break in LSN chain'

Comment: the Differential backup is before Full Backup. You can't restore an earlier differential backup

Comment: i am doing the same First Full Back Up then Differential

Comment: Restore FULL backup with `NORECOVERY` then DIFF with `RECOVERY`

Comment: Maybe it's the problem mentioned here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128280/unable-to-create-restore-plan-due-to-break-in-lsn-chain

Answer (score 2):

When you backup database, in `backup header` and in msdb (`backupset` table) some data is written.

In case of full and differential backup there are `database_backup_lsn`, `checkpoint_lsn`, `is_copy_only` of interest.

You can restore `differential` backup only over **corresponding** `full` backup.

To find out the correct `full backup` for given `differential backup` you should consider only full backups that are NOT copy_only. The corresponding full backup will have `checkpoint_lsn` equal to `database_backup_lsn` of given differential backup.

Here is the picture where I mark with the same color `full backup`s that can be base for `differential backup`s:

[image]

Now for example you want to find the corresponding `full backup`.

First you should find the differential backup `database_backup_lsn`, in my example it's 23064679000002372000077. Then make a query like this and you'll find the corresponding `full` backup.

```
select type,
       backup_start_date, 
       backup_finish_date,
       database_backup_lsn,
       checkpoint_lsn,
       is_copy_only,
       f.family_sequence_number,
       f.physical_device_name
from msdb..backupset s 
     join msdb..backupmediafamily f
        on f.media_set_id = s.media_set_id  
where database_name = 'basedati_bi' and type = 'D' and is_copy_only = 0 and checkpoint_lsn = 23064679000002372000077
```

Comment: What is the "checkpoint_lsn" of the differential backup? Can it be used to find the appropriate logbackup to restore over the differential backup?